# How to delete unnamed conda environemt

Tags: anaconda, conda, environment, navigator

I am using Anaconda on macOS. Apart from the base environment, I created pip when I am installing libraries available only from that channel.

But I have one called 'anaconda3' which I can see in Navigator

[image]

and also see when checking envs in terminal:

```
% conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/marek/opt/anaconda3
pip_env                  /Users/marek/opt/anaconda3/envs/pip_env
                         /opt/anaconda3
```

The thing is that it works strangely, it seems to be at the same location as base but does not work as base env. I can switch it and install different libraries etc. But it works strangely and I cannot update any apps (jupyter, spyder) in it so I want to delete but it is not possible as it has no name.

my goal is to remove that anconda3 (/opt/anaconda3 without any name in terminal) environment

Comment: To me it looks like you installed Anaconda twice - with and without elevated privileges. I'd recommend [full uninstallation of everything](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/), then reinstall only with a user install.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove nameless environments using prefix:

`conda env remove -p /opt/anaconda3`

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine that your `pip_env` environment is in the envs subfolder. This is the default location. You can delete in 3 ways:

```
conda env remove --name pip_env
```

or

```
conda remove --all --prefix "/Users/marek/opt/anaconda3/envs/pip_env"
```

or you simply delete the folder using your shell. Conda environments are self contained.

Comment: But I do not want to remove my pipenv. I want to remove that last one - /opt/anaconda3 (in terminal) or anaconda3 in Navigator selection
it seems like some mashup between base env. But it is impossible to update applications inside this environment.

Comment: I mean in my envs folder I have only one environment - pip_env (which I want). The only think is that anaconda3 environment outside 'base' environment. But in a navigartor they work as two different envs (different version, different libraries)

Comment: Maybe I can just ignore it and use either base environment and the environments I created. But it is confusing